# Transform table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

can you please help with the question:

How do I transform a table in this format:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you want to do is called "unpivot". Search around here and you'll find a ton.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are different products with different syntax. Please choose ***one***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
select person, 'Salary' as metric, salary as metric_value from t
union all
select person, 'Spend', spend from t
```

Comment: @MatBailie Yeah, I need a coffee.

Comment: better than your first attempt! Just change the doublequote with singlequote for some safety as the rdbms is unclear ;)

Comment: @ThomasG I'll make coffee double.